# Regression Trees explanation

Tags: regression, cart

I am trying to implement a regression tree but I do not understand the maths completely. So given this answer:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-decision-trees-for-regression-work

I do not understand this formula:

[image]

So what is y1 bar and y2 bar ?

As I build my tree while looping through splits I will have 2 parts each time. So y1-bar is the average of the y values of the left part? Same for y2-bar?

If it is then is just a scalar? So I subtract a scalar from a vector and sum it's resulting elements ?

So if yi = [1,9,8,9,9,1,4] then y1-bar (mean) is 5.857 ? So the sum will be 
sum[yi - mean(yi)] = 2.6645352591003757e-15 ?

Comment: Shouldn't those be squared?

Comment: If you subtract the mean from a sample and then sum the differences you will get zero so I suspect @generic_user is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, like this:
(1-5.857) + (9-5.857) + (8-5.857) + (9-5.857) + (9-5.857) + (1-5.857) + (4-5.857) = .000999.

What you're not understanding about the formula is its context. Here's the full paragraph you cite:

"The method starts by searching for every distinct values of all its predictors, and splitting the value of a predictor that minimizes the following statistic (other regression tree models have different optimization criteria):

SSE=∑i∈S1(yi−y1¯)+∑i∈S2(yi−y2¯)SSE=∑i∈S1(yi−y1¯)+∑i∈S2(yi−y2¯)

where y1¯ and y2¯ are the average values of the dependent variable in groups S1 and S2."

The formula here measures a type of variance (because it sums the difference between the average and each item). The overall goal of the regression tree is to  minimize variance (and determine relative strength of factors), by recursively selecting whichever split will lead to the greatest reduction in variance. Other models use standard deviation [sqr rt of (∑i∈S(y−y¯)/(n - 1)] instead, like this one: http://www.saedsayad.com/decision_tree_reg.htm (which you've probably already read, as it was one of the answers to the question on Quora)

Hope this is sorta helpful.

Comment: The calculation you outline always gives zero (to machine precision so there must be something wrong.

Comment: what calculation do you mean?
i think the example numbers that OP supplied just happen to work out to close to zero. If you replace the 1s with 10s, it comes out to 18.01 or so.
or do you mean the formula that OP was asking about? it doubled when copypasted... but it shouldn't equal zero all the time.

Comment: If you subtract the mean from a sample and sum the differences you always get zero.

Comment: oh duh. and the .0009 is from rounding.

Comment: yeah, whoever put up the original formula forgot to square root it. this is the problem with the formula.

Comment: @IvanBaracus you should perhaps delete or edit the answer if you now agree it's incorrect